# Library for Image Recognition in Obj-C?

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, image-recognition

I'm looking for some library that will allow me to identify black dots on a white background. Preferably in C or objective-c.

Also, what keywords can I use in my search for such algorithms? I've found a lot of stuff about image recognition but nothing that ressembles what I'm looking for.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a possibility to use OpenCV in obj-c

The general API can be found at: [http://opencv.willowgarage.com/](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome)

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @delirial I also have to implement the same feature.Can you please provide some sample code or link through which you implement this feature or provide me the right direction which I should follow to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV vs. Apple iPhone](http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/04/opencv-vs-apple-iphone/) article shows 2 approaches to get OpenCV on iPhone, may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try imagemagick.
http://www.imagemagick.org/